# off callback different than original on function callback

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all I'm not using jquery I'm building my own vanilla javascript library. Below is my off function and then there is my events wrapper function, Have a look at how I made my off function and then have a look at my events function. What I have done is create my own 'off' callback function which is different than my 'on' function callback - so I can have an exit callback when removing my event listener. Does what I have done make sense - open for discussion

```
off: function(event, selector, callback, capture) {

  if (typeof (selector) === 'function') {
    capture = callback;
    callback = selector || null;
  }

  selector = typeof selector == 'string' ? selector : null;
  capture = capture ? true : false;

  if(selector) {
    let obj = $(selector, this.$el);

    if(obj.$elems.length) {

      obj.$elems.forEach(function(el, i) {
        evts.remove(event, el, callback, capture);
      });

    } else if(obj.$el){        
      evts.remove(event, obj.$el, callback, capture);
    }

    return this;
  }


  if(this.$elems && this.$elems.length) {
    this.$elems.forEach(function(el, i) {
      evts.remove(event, el, callback, capture);
    });
  } else {
    evts.remove(event, this.$el, callback, capture);
  }

  return this;
}
```

events wrapper

```
var evts = (function () {
  'use strict';

  var listeners = [],
      add,
      remove;

  add = function (evt, elem, fn, capture) {
    var callback = function (evt) {      
      fn.call(elem, evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
    };

    listeners.push({
      evt: evt,
      elem: elem,
      fn: fn,
      callback: callback,
      capture, capture,
      removed: false
    });

    elem.addEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
  };

  remove = function (evt, elem, fn, capture) {

    var callback = function (evt) {
      return fn ? fn.call(elem, evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement) : null;
    };

    listeners.forEach(function (obj, i) {
      if (obj.evt === evt && obj.elem === elem && 
          !obj.removed) {
        obj.removed = true;

        if(callback && callback !== obj.callback) {
          callback();
        }

        callback = obj.callback;
        listeners.splice(i, 1);

        return false;
      }
    });

    elem.removeEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
  };

  return {
    add: add,
    remove: remove
  };
}());
```

Example:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).off('click', function(e) { alert('good bye') });
});
```

Comment: I think you over-engineering. Does these *overload*s really used?

Comment: plus I don't really get the reason behind `off`'s callback.